# Unable to configure the Network Settings in centos 7

Tags: terminal

I am unable to run "system-config-network-tui" command in centos 7. Returns the error

> bash: system-config-Network-tui: command not found

I've already installed the package via

```
yum install NetworkManager-tui
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the command  `nmtui`; when in doubt, look at documentation: [installation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Networking_Config_Using_nmtui.html) and [usage](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_Text_User_Interface_nmtui.html) from Redhat.

Answer (score 2):

You have several tools to configure the network on Centos 7.

- nmtui (From the package NetworkManager-tui)
- mmcli (From the package NetworkManager)
- nm-connection-editor (If you have a GUI running Gnome Desktop Environment)

Please take note that in Centos 7 the default network service is managed by the NetworkManager which is a dynamic network control and configuration daemon.

I would suggest you to have a look at the Official Documentation of RHEL 7, which is identical to the Centos 7 operating system.

Documentation : [Networking Guide RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/)

Answer (score 1):

There is [simple TUI](http://gotechnies.com/network-setup-centos-7/) command to configure whether you are configuring the network on Server or on Local System.

Use the below command and follow the steps-:

```
$ sudo nmtui
```

After configure the network. Activate the network.
Restart the network service.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart network
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
system-network-config-tui &
```