# In the VMware I add the second NIC to the VM， why the directory network-scripts/ do not generate the ifcfg-eno33554984?

Tags: centos, configuration, network-interface, vmware

In the VMware workstation, I have a VM(CentOS 7.2). Before, I only have one NIC for the VM; it used the NAT network model. I configured the IP for the NIC in VM, and it works fine.

But I added another, and rebooted the VM.
I use the `ip a` to show the NICs state.

[image]

(Because I am remote to the host machine, so I can not copy the code form the VMware Workstation, so I only can post snapshot), You see there is two NICs, I added it successfully.

But I can not find the configuration file(`ifcfg-eno33554984`) under the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` directory, it did not generate:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

You know if I add three NICs in the beginning, there will generate three ifcfg-* files here.

Comment: What is the question here?  If you want a configuration file for the new interface, you can create and edit it.

Comment: Related: [Unable to configure the Network Settings in centos 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188750/unable-to-configure-the-network-settings-in-centos-7)

Comment: @user4556274 why it nmt like the first generaty by system?

Comment: @aircraft, if your question is "Why is a configuration file for an added interface on CentOS not automatically generated by the system?", then please edit your question to state that.  This is a question-and-answer site, so questions should be in the form of a question.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No, I config the NIC in the configuration file, not use the tools.